# Azure Boards : Query - Pending Work for an Epic

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to make a query that shows me under a structure Epic -> Feature -> Release -> User Story -> Tasks, all pending tasks under a specific Iteration Path

I tried with tree of work items, but it just shows until mu User Story

**My Azure Devops**

[image: My Azure Devops]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Boards : Query - Pending Work for an Epic

I could confirm that your query conditions are correct, I could use it to list all the parent workitems:

[image]

So, please to check if the workitem `Epic`,`Feature`,`Release` are match all the conditions for the `Area Path` and `Iteration Path`.

For example, I have change the `Iteration Path` of Epic from `LeoTest\Iteration 2` to `LeoTest\Iteration 1`, then it will lost in my query:

[image]

The query result:

[image]